# Exclude fields from being indexed by Elasticsearch via CouchDB-River

Tags: couchdb, elasticsearch

I am indexing ealsticsearch with the CouchDB-River plugin. At the moment I am trying to implement search for users, where a simplified document would look something like this:

```
{
  username: "john",
  firstname: "John",
  lastname: "Doe",
  email: "john.doe@example.com",
  password: "someHash"
}
```

I don't want the password to be indexed in ES because I don't see any use for doing this, but maybe I am wrong here (I am fairly new to ES)?

I did set up the River by executing:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost/_river/st_user/_meta' -d '{
  "type" : "couchdb",
  "couchdb" : {
    "host" : "localhost",
    "port" : 5984,
    "db" : "sportstracker_usertest",
    "ignore_attachments":true,
    "filter" : null
    }
  },
  "index" : {
    "index" : "tracker",
    "type" : "user",
    "bulk_size" : "100",
    "bulk_timeout" : "10ms"
  }
}'
```

Can you implement this via the River (Script Filters) or the mapping of ES?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Elasticsearch's CouchDB river documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.cn/guide/reference/river/couchdb.html)

```
{
  "type" : "couchdb",
  "couchdb" : {
    "host" : "localhost",
    "port" : 5984,
    "db" : "sportstracker_usertest",
    "ignore_attachments":true,
    "filter" : "NAME_OF_FILTER_IN_COUCHDB",
    "filter_params" : {
      "FIRST_PARAMETER_ON_THAT_FILTER" : "VALUE_YOU_WANT_TO_PASS",
      "userStatus" : "online",
      "minSubscriptors" : "1"
    }
  },
  "index" : {
    "index" : "tracker",
    "type" : "user",
    "bulk_size" : "100",
    "bulk_timeout" : "10ms"
  }
}
```

Although a filter can only filter whole documents, [following CouchDB 1.2 it is possible to provide a view as filter](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.4.x/changes.html).

Beside using a filter, Elasticsearch has a `script` hook to preprocess input data. [It is possible to mutate document in this hook and Elasticsearch stores the mutated version](http://www.elasticsearch.cn/guide/reference/river/couchdb.html).

```
{
  "type" : "couchdb",
  "couchdb" : {
    "script" : "ctx.doc.password = undefined"
  },
  "index" : {
  }
}
```